# Selenium webdriver add_cookies working but can't log in

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cookies

Hello I'm using selenium and chrome driver to authomatically log in on amazon.jp and amazon.de.

1. I manually logged in on amazon.jp and checked the cookies
2. got cookies with get_cookies() and checked the list is okay
3. I opened the selenium driver and moved to amazon.jp and used add_cookies()
4. checked the cookies were added and it was same to what I got from "get_cookies()"
5. I moved to amazon.jp again and it seems that sign-in didn't work

The same process worked for taobao and other sites, so does Amazon uses some different ways(plus cookies) to log in?